# jQuery autocomplete doesn't send any request

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I already created many autocomplete, and there has never been a problem.
This time, I tried to insert an autocomplete in an existing page (very complex and having many javascript calls)

My code is simple like that :

```
$('#named_invitees_0_user_id').autocomplete({
  source: 'www.bidon.com'
});
```

I tried to :

- Charge this javascript inside a  $(document).ready()  function
- Not charge this javascript on page loading, then execute the previous code in Firebug console
- Add some parameters to autocomplete (minLength, disabled, delay, beforeSend, ...)
- Set an array on source

In this 2 cases, my input 'understand' my autocomplete function, because it takes some of autocomplete specific attributes

```
<input id="named_invitees_0_user_id" name="named_invitees[0][user_id]" type="text" value="aaaa" autocomplete="off" class="ac_input">
```

But NO request is never send when I wrote something on my input (regarding the Firebug Network activity). I think some of the javascript already present on the page is tracking control of this query, but I have no idea what it can be.

And you ?

Edit:

Thanks to your replies. I follow your suggestions :

- try to set an array as 'source' : doesn't change anything
- remove all the JS of this page : only jQuery-1.4.3 and jQuery-ui-1.8.20 were loaded : doesn't change anything
- change the value of minLength to 1 : doesn't change anything
- check if the source url returns JSON : it's confirmed
- check if the source url is on my website namespace : it's confirmed

Edit2:

Problem found !

There was an hidden JS code somewhere... An old "autocomplete" jquery include. Result : 2 autocomplete were defined.
I delete this hidden code and everything works ok !

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: Is bidon your website?  Also, you do know that it's currently down, right?

Comment: bidon is a french word as "foobar". I can write '/', '#', or real path to my website (it works on other pages), this change nothing.

Comment: Since the page is "very complex", you may want to back out all JS on the page except this script and jQuery/jQuery UI. If it doesn't work, debug (or update your question). If it *does* work, keep adding scripts back until you find the conflict.

Comment: What is the value of `minLength`? Maybe some existing code sets this globally to some huge value. Alternatively, someone might overwrite `.autocomplete()`.

Comment: I edit my first message to reply.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your source is outputting proper json.

check http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote for documentation and sample code

here's an example:

```
 $( "#named_invitees_0_user_id" ).autocomplete({
      source: "search.php",
      minLength: 2
    });
```

use ":" after source!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the ":" in my message, not in my code. The source can output XHTML, JSON, JS, XML, or anything : autocomplete MUST send a request to check the type. No request were sent.

Comment: Yes, if no request is sent, "search.php" (or any source) is irrelevant until the request actually leaves the browser.

Comment: then make sure your source and page autocomplete is being used on is hosted on same domain. Cross domain requests can't be sent using ajax.
You can also try sending an ajax request using $.ajax to make sure that ajax is working properly

Comment: and no error in console? CTRL+SHIFT+J and see if you have any errors in console.